# How does the Facebook 'share' button on Stack overflow work?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, social-networking

I am looking to add social icons to our site, giving customers the ability to "like", tweet and share content on their facebook and twitter profiles. I have noticed to the left of this box, the facebook and twitter icons do **exactly** what I am trying to accomplish but I am not familiar with how to do this. Looking at the source code, there are JS references to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  StackExchange.ready(function() {
    var shareUrl = "http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2fq%2f7505636%2f337690";
    var shareMsg = "Advice+integrating+Facebook+%27share%27+and+link%2fimage+capabilities+with+our+site";   
    StackExchange.share.facebook($("#fb-share-7505636"), shareUrl, shareMsg);
    StackExchange.share.twitter($("#twitter-share-7505636"), shareUrl, shareMsg);
});
</script>
```

Our site works this way: While anybody can visit the primary site at any time, individuals can sign up as representatives with their own unique URL that acts as a referrer to give 'credit' on rewards. I have reviewed the facebook developer site and to be honest I am slightly overwhelmed. I want to give our members the ability to click a Facebook icon from within their dashboard, prompting them to post on their wall with a set image, set title, and description. I have read in the documentation this is done by setting meta tags in the head but it does not seem to matter for my site (or I am clearly doing it wrong).

What if the URL facebook is looking for (share URL) is behind a password protected page or an area of the site which would not allow content based on a missing PHP SESSION variable?

### Edit

I have also seen a lot on the net which says I have to integrate the Facebook JS SDK but then goes on to talk about authentication/permission to write on walls, etc. Yes the link to the left **does not** ask for permission to do anything other than to 1) log into the FB account, 2) post on the user's wall.
[This site is a perfect example](http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/new-javascript-sdk-oauth-2-0-based-fbconnect-tutorial/)

The link above is great but it assumes I need to authorize a 'share' which does not occur on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click on the share button, you call a script on facebook.com that will then in turn  access the page pointed to in the querystring (?u=xxxxxx).

Facebook will parse that page and grab the first few images it finds, a description and title from the page. That is what it shows to you and allows you to add some additional text (as well as edit the title/description/and choose different images).

If that page contains the specific meta tags that facebook asks you to add to the page, then they'll use those to populate the title/description/image. This allows the webpage author to control how their page shows up in a facebook feed (although the user could still edit it before posting). These meta tags would need to be in that particular page to be used by facebook.

If facebook cannot access the page because it's password protected, etc. - then it cannot parse the meta tags and will then just show the user the URL as the title with no description and thumbnail.

Comment: what script is being called on FB and how do they get the content? I believe it is more than this because I can easily replace the URL in the share.php link above and it will **post** to facebook walls but does not include image or content

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to the link you had up there on an earlier version. So here's the answer:  It's all in the URL: `http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fq%2F7505636%2F844726&ref=fbshare&t=How+does+the+Facebook+%27share%27+button+on+Stack+overflow+work%3F` <-- this is the URL that stackoverflow calls when you click on the FB share button on the post. If you use this, then the user will have to authenticate before they post to their page. You will not be able to post for them, therefore you won't need to ask for permissions etc.

Comment: Again, the sharer.php script will grab the image/description from the page when it accesses that page.

Comment: the link before had the same format, different site but I see what you are saying. Is there not a way to have it pull title/description/image from say an existing facebook page? Perhaps this is a totally different question but if I can create a 'share' button by simply modifying meta tags and a link, what is the purpose of utilizing something like the JS SDK 2.0 or PHP 3.0 SDK other than to log a user in to a site?

Comment: also - if they are simply pointing to a PHP script, what is the JS function above (viewed on this pages source code) used for then?

Comment: @JM4: the SDKs are used to allow you to post on their behalf; the share scripts are used to allow them to post to their wall from a link on your page.

Comment: @JM4: the StackExchange function is used to construct the URL and the popup for the share page.